# Cocoa get Power Adapter Status

Tags: cocoa, macos-carbon, iokit

I'm currently working on a Backup Application, and I have received a lot of requests for features to be added recently, and the top one of them is adding a checkbox like "Back Up when on Battery Power" like Time Machine has.

So, is there a way I can get the status of the Power Adapter (plugged in and plugged in)? I assume that if one had a Desktop Mac, like iMac, etc, I would probably just get Plugged In all the time. Therefore, I need means of detecting if the computer is a portable or not.

I assume IOKit would be a library to look at, but I simply could not find anything in the docs, that are barely existent anyways on that Framework. Then, since it is an older Carbon Framework, is there a way to register a callback that gets called when that power state changes? That way I can properly implement this checkbox's functionality.

I'd appreciate help in clarifying this subject.

Comment: Haven't used IOKit myself, but this header could be useful: http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/PowerManagement/PowerManagement-211/AppleSmartBatteryManager/AppleSmartBattery.h

Comment: I did look at that file, and it seemed like the place to look, but I had to do it a different approach since there appear to be some issues with the API. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IOPowerSources.h has the functions you need.  Start with `IOPSNotificationCreateRunLoopSource()` to create a run loop source and in your callback interrogate the power source info starting with `IOPSCopyPowerSourcesInfo()` and working your way down.  There may be better examples, but [this file](http://context-macosx.googlecode.com/svn-history/r138/trunk/Tools/Applications/Pennyworth/PowerObserver.m) appears to be a reasonable demonstration of how it's done; enough to get you started.

Comment: Thanks, I had to do a bit of 'API Dumpster Diving' as I like to call it to find those methods, but I did manage to figure out how to do it, but it seems to be a tad inefficient. It puts the entire relevant info into an CFDictionaryRef, then convert that to an NSDictionary, and I just access it the way I'm used to. I also use this to enable that checkbox only if it's a Mac with battery, and of course to check if the IOPSNotification is really required to junk up my Run Loop more than it already is anyways.