# determining the power source used (Macintosh)

Tags: xcode, macos

For a Mac application, I would need to test what kind of power source the computer is using at the moment, and get notified when that power source changes (i.e. switching to battery power).

Is there a way to do this? I haven't found anything like that in the documentation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cocoa get Power Adapter Status](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4552286/cocoa-get-power-adapter-status)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I  believe you can use the I/O Kit framework for this, specifically the [IOPowerSources.h](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/IOKit/IOPowerSources_h/) functions. (The IOPSNotificationCreateRunLoopSource callback will let you know if a power source has been connected/disconnected.)